# How to fire an event after clicking an option in a select?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm trying to set up a test function where an alert is displayed when the user clicks a specific option in a `<select>` element:

```
<script>
function test() {
    var body = document.getElementById("body");
    var select = document.createElement("select");
    var defaultOpt = document.createElement("option");
    defaultOpt.label = "Default Option";
    var mainOpt = document.createElement("option");
    mainOpt.label = "Click this option";

    mainOpt.onClick = alert("It works!");

    select.appendChild(defaultOpt);
    select.appendChild(mainOpt);
    body.appendChild(select);
}
</script>

<body id="body">
    <input type="button" value="Start" onclick="test();" />
</body>
```

It is only when I click the "Start" button, however, that the alert displays, not when I click the designated option in the select. Can anyone tell me how to set this up correctly?

Comment: You should bind a `change` event handler to the `select` element instead. But the reason why the `alert` shows is because you are calling it immediately. `var foo = bar();` executes `bar` and assigns the return value to `foo`. That's normal JS behavior and doesn't magically change with event handlers. Have a look at http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html to learn more about traditional event handlers. It has [section specifically about your problem](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html#link2).

Comment: ^^ what he said, options don't fire mouse events in all browsers, and as such can't be reliably used with click handlers.

Comment: JavaScript events should be lowercase. Notice you have `onClick`, were it should be `onclick`. Also, to work an alert like that you should put it inside an Anonymous function, like: `mainOpt.onclick = function(){alert('It Works!')}`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]+option+click+event

Comment: Thank you all for your input; I added an anonymous function as @PHPglue suggested and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `selectElement.onchange` event. This may require that your select Element loses focus, in some older Browsers, to fire the event.

```
//<![CDATA[
// common.js
var doc = document, bod = doc.body, IE = parseFloat(navigator.appVersion.split('MSIE')[1]);
bod.className = 'js';
function gteIE(version, className){
  if(IE >= version)bod.className = className;
}
function E(e){
  return doc.getElementById(e);
}
//]]>

//<[CDATA[
// yourpage.js
function test(){
  var sel = doc.createElement('select'), defaultOpt = doc.createElement('option');
  var mainOpt = doc.createElement('option');
  defaultOpt.value = defaultOpt.label = 'Default Option';
  mainOpt.value = mainOpt.label = 'Click this option';
  sel.appendChild(defaultOpt); sel.appendChild(mainOpt);
  sel.onchange = function(){
    if(this.value === defaultOpt.value){
      alert('It Works!');
    }
  }
  bod.appendChild(sel);
}
test();
//]]>
```

Or just notice that JavaScript events should be lowercase. Notice you have `onClick`, where it should be `onclick`. Also, to work an alert like that you should put it inside an Anonymous function, like:

```
 mainOpt.onclick = function(){
   alert('It Works!');
 }
```

Comment: I think the `change` event fires without the select element loosing focus.

Comment: Don't want to persist on this, but even in FF 3.6 the change event fires immediately. I didn't try any earlier version, but I think we can safely assume that this works in Firefox for quite a while now.

Comment: Maybe it was another Browser I was testing on, but I have seen the problem in the past. Thanks.